# Python: Apply function, exp, to every ele of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
v = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (200, 785))
x is 60000 by 785


for ele in x:

    a = np.dot(v, ele.T)

    h = tanh(a)





def tanh(value):
   value = np.clip(value, -20, 20)
   return 2*sigmoid(2*value) -1

def sigmoid(value):
   return 1.0/(1+math.exp(-value))
```

I'm getting the error, "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
", saying I can't apply the sigmoid like that, element-wise.

***Basically, the problem is: a is 200 by 1, and I want to do tanh(a).***
Also, I don't quite understand why I'm allowed to apply a simpler function like +1 element-wise, but not sigmoid, which involves exp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`.  The latter doesn't support NumPy arrays.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to click the checkmark on the left to "accept" this answer if it solved your problem.